# How can I append a string item as a sublist item in a list?

Tags: python

How can I append a string type item always as a sublist to my main list?

```
list_of_similarities = []

list_of_similarities.append('A')
list_of_similarities.append('B')
list_of_similarities.append('C')
list_of_similarities.append('D')
```

Actual Output:

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Expected Output

```
mylist = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']]
```

Comment: `.append(['A'])`?

Comment: Append lists: `list_of_similarities.append(['A'])`, ...

Comment: That was easy, thank you all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
list_of_similarities.append(['D'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using a `list comprehension`

```
list_of_similarities = [list(letter) for letter in ["A","B","C","D"]]

print(list_of_similarities)
```

Output:

```
[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the built in `map` method.

```
>>> list_of_similarities = list(map(list, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']))
>>> list_of_similarities
[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']]
```

Also for just uppercase letters you could even do this:

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> list(map(list, ascii_uppercase[:4]))
[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']]
```